# How can i redirect all subfolders to a single root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all calls to `mysite.com/api/foo/bar/json?param1=1...` to `mysite.com/api`

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^api/?(.*)" "/api" [R=302]
```

But it doesn't work because it redirects in a loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the destination path you are redirecting to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/?$
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*) /api [R=302]
```

Comment: In addition you should also almost always include L flag with redirects including the cond.

Answer (score 0):

First check file permission maybe you don't have to made edit on the `.htaccess` file. Then insert this line of code.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Your rule will create a permanent redirect loop, as it's unconditionaly redirecting the request.